# Porting to Qt5.6 or advanced causes application to use ANGLE instead of OpnelGL 3.x and causes black screen instead of rendering actual image

Tags: qt5.5, qt5.6, qopenglfunctions

I have recently ported our application from Qt5.5 to Qt5.12.1. On i5 processor Windows 10 the application runs fine. However on i3 Windows 10 Pc's we get a nothing but a black screen. The application runs fine on i3 Windows 8 though.

On further digging, we found out that the issue occurs only on devices where OpenGL version is 3.x and it works when the OpenGL version is 4.0+. That's why it worked in i3 windows8 which has 4.0 version of OpenGL.

For Qt5.5 it works, but if we port to even Qt5.6 it does not work. We cannot find anything on release notes or known bugs from Qt. We are using OpenGLfunctions and QOpenGlWindow.

Information from the logs of **Qt5.5** build:
**glVersion 3.1.0 - Build 9.17.10.4459**

Information from the logs of **Qt5.6 and 5.12.1** builds in the same machine and same environment:
**glVersion - OpenGL ES 2.0 (ANGLE 2.1.0.57ea533f79a7)**

I would like to know whether I am missing something that I should do while porting Qt versions? or is it a bug in Qt?

How can I force Qt to use available OpenGL version instead of using ANGLE?

I would also like to know if we can downgrade OpenGL version of the windows 10 to re-create it easily on other devices as well for testing purposes.

Thank You.